# bash - how to grep a string within a file and index with the file name

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have a few thousand files each within their own folder and I want to link a specific string ID with the file name.
So for example here I have a couple of different folders :

```
Folder_1
file_abc.txt
Sample-001-abc

Folder_2
file_efg.txt
Sample-002-efg

Folder_3
file_hig.txt
Sample-003-hig
```

and I would like to grep based on the string "Sample" and link that string to the filename each is located in, to ensure I have the correct sample/filename order. Essentially, I would like to output a separate file that looks like this:

```
Filename_sample_linked.txt
file_abc.txt Sample-001-abc
file_efg.txt Sample-002-efg
file_hig.txt Sample-003-hig
...etc
```

I can grab all the IDs with the following:

```
find dir/*.txt -type f -exec grep -H 'Sample' {} + >> List_of_samples.txt
```

but am not quite sure how to link that with the file name that the string came from. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `grep -H` should prefix the filename of matching lines, what is the output you get and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: So when I try to specify the file name (.vcf.gz) it gives me an error saying "no such file or directory". If I do not specify ".vcf.gz" and just do "find dir/" , it seems to skip over the ".vcf.gz" files and goes into text files only. The same thing occurs even if I include "-name '*.vcf.gz'"

Comment: please update the question with the lines from `List_of_samples.txt` that correspond to your sample input/output

Comment: what does *`ensure I have the correct sample/filename order`* mean? what would an *`incorrect`* sample look like and what would you do with it? the first half of the question sounds (to me) like you're trying to build the `Sample-###-###` string from the folder and file names ... if this is the case, none of the question actually shows your attempt to build said strings nor how you would compare (?) the strings with the results from the `grep` ... ???

Comment: To process `*.gz` files, you can try `zgrep` if you have it, instead of using `grep`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `sed`.

If you actually *meant* for that filename to be line 1:

```
$: sed -E '1{s/.*/Filename_sample_linked.txt/;p;d}; /[.]txt/{N;s/\n/ /}; /^$/{N;d}' file
Filename_sample_linked.txt
file_abc.txt Sample-001-abc
file_efg.txt Sample-002-efg
file_hig.txt Sample-003-hig
```

Otherwise, replace `1{s/.*/Filename_sample_linked.txt/;p;d};` with just `1d;` maybe.
I will assume you did NOT mean for the last line to literally be `...etc`.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

1. generate a script via "meta programming"
2. run it
3. save the output

Sometimes, if you can solve a problem by doing simple steps repetitively, then all you need to do is figure out the steps and repeat them. The advantage of this approach is that it's not very sophisticated and relatively easy to do.

- go to the folder
- list the two files side by side
- save that to a list

In shell-speak, that could look like this:

```
cd Folder_1; echo file_* Sample*; cd ..
cd Folder_3; echo file_* Sample*; cd ..
```

I can show you how to do this many times, but first let's have some fun.

#### setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
md () { mkdir -p "$1"; cd "$1"; pwd; }
ran3() { tr -dc '[[:alnum:]]' </dev/urandom  | dd bs=${1:-3} count=1 status=none ; }
w80()  { echo $(( 20 + 80 * RANDOM / 65536 )); }
w20()  { echo $(( 3  + 20 * RANDOM / 65536 )); }

# Initial setup

md Folder_1
touch file_abc.txt
touch Sample-001-abc
cd ..

md Folder_2
touch file_efg.txt
touch Sample-002-efg
cd ..

md Folder_3
touch file_hig.txt
touch Sample-003-hig
cd ..

# More folders with 3-char comparison patterns
s=0
s=$( find -name Sample\* | wc -l )
(( s++ ))
max=$(( s + 20 ))


while [[ $s -lt $max ]]; do
    md Folder_$s
    str=`ran3`
    printf -v ss '%03d' $s
    touch file_$str.txt
    touch Sample-$ss-$str
    (( s++ ))
    cd ..
done

# More folders with random names
max=$(( max + 20 ))
while [[ $s -lt $max ]]; do
    fstr=`ran3 $(w80)`
    md ${fstr}_$s
    str=`ran3 $(w20)`
    printf -v ss '%03d' $s
    touch file_$str.txt
    touch Sample-$ss-$str
    (( s++ ))
    cd ..
done
```

I ran that a few times and now I have:

```
./Folder_143/file_nhE.txt
./Folder_143/Sample-143-nhE
./yHb9aSWkRDXqQfITkrqplQQMH[cNdMTYt_144/file_W9eDdDIEN.txt
./yHb9aSWkRDXqQfITkrqplQQMH[cNdMTYt_144/Sample-144-W9eDdDIEN
./ClauM57QCXPCqLPBHUMERI6Vxc_145/file_vhTSZfTh.txt
./ClauM57QCXPCqLPBHUMERI6Vxc_145/Sample-145-vhTSZfTh
./kpXndK8eapnUJKf9XvFZgnY31kUVNmUkHDp1ey[Q3IsY53EOQ_146/file_b[rj3ft.txt
./kpXndK8eapnUJKf9XvFZgnY31kUVNmUkHDp1ey[Q3IsY53EOQ_146/Sample-146-b[rj3ft
./mx]Yrj5eEa4PlEL2snmYOttZwc]Vi4rSCJ_147/file_]OyWwrVd0RN.txt
./mx]Yrj5eEa4PlEL2snmYOttZwc]Vi4rSCJ_147/Sample-147-]OyWwrVd0RN
./Zpi1sip87UmM85gd[dh]9sQn5ZE5rjBGA[[9ae_148/file_uQPZU[Tn[.txt
```

#### step 1 (generate the meta script)

```
find -name Sample\* -type f \
  -printf "cd $PWD"';s="%f"; cd %h ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt %f\n'
```

Here we use find to make a bunch of commands for us, that we can run. Mixing quotes like "ABC"'123' into a single string ABC123 is just a clever way to interpolate some variables, while passing others to -printf for later.

> "cd $PWD"

Go to the base folder before each sub-folder.

> ';s="%f"; cd %h ;

End the cd-pwd and asign the basename to s.
Go to the dirname of each found Samlple* file.

> echo file_${s##*-}.txt %f\n'

Print the two files side by side.
`${s##GLOB}` means remove everything from the start of the s string that matches GLOB. So effectively remove everything up to and with the last dash.

The %f and %h macros are available when using `find -printf`, if that was unclear.

```
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-138-Lj]"; cd ./Folder_138 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-138-Lj]
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-139-pad"; cd ./Folder_139 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-139-pad
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-140-ImN"; cd ./Folder_140 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-140-ImN
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-141-nxr"; cd ./Folder_141 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-141-nxr
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-142-4Di"; cd ./Folder_142 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-142-4Di
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-143-nhE"; cd ./Folder_143 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-143-nhE
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-144-W9eDdDIEN"; cd ./yHb9aSWkRDXqQfITkrqplQQMH[cNdMTYt_144 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-144-W9eDdDIEN
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-145-vhTSZfTh"; cd ./ClauM57QCXPCqLPBHUMERI6Vxc_145 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-145-vhTSZfTh
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-146-b[rj3ft"; cd ./kpXndK8eapnUJKf9XvFZgnY31kUVNmUkHDp1ey[Q3IsY53EOQ_146 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-146-b[rj3ft
```

Keep in mind that this solution is fragile and relies on the **regularity** of the names of the input files / folders. If you are working with unpredictable data, you may need to think harder...

#### step 2 (run the meta script)

```
$ find -name Sample\* -type f \
    -printf "cd $PWD"';s="%f"; cd %h ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt %f\n' \
  | bash -x
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-001-abc"; cd ./Folder_1 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-001-abc
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-002-efg"; cd ./Folder_2 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-002-efg
cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link;s="Sample-003-hig"; cd ./Folder_3 ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt Sample-003-hig
(...)
+ cd './v0a7F1K5P[fKL5NSYXaMZdFdGV7UCK_154'
+ echo file_R0IZENm2ni.txt Sample-154-R0IZENm2ni
file_R0IZENm2ni.txt Sample-154-R0IZENm2ni
+ cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link
+ s=Sample-155-MEuAFsvztX
+ cd ./tKUlAFlPy2zq2xiZhruhS9U2VDnNQc7LiwYkUxL_155
+ echo file_MEuAFsvztX.txt Sample-155-MEuAFsvztX
file_MEuAFsvztX.txt Sample-155-MEuAFsvztX
+ cd /home/jaroslav/tmp/so-link
+ s='Sample-156-M7e]VOOHFz'
+ cd './3zVn7Z9ltN2MpmS[lo]6DCgv4RFEdX9XDoskFY0p_156'
+ echo 'file_M7e]VOOHFz.txt' 'Sample-156-M7e]VOOHFz'
file_M7e]VOOHFz.txt Sample-156-M7e]VOOHFz
(...)
```

#### step 3 (save the output)

```
$ find -name Sample\* -type f \
     -printf "cd $PWD"';s="%f"; cd %h ; echo file_${s##*-}.txt %f\n' \
  | bash | column -t \
  | tee  /tmp/list
(...)
file_ImN.txt           Sample-140-ImN
file_nxr.txt           Sample-141-nxr
file_4Di.txt           Sample-142-4Di
file_nhE.txt           Sample-143-nhE
file_W9eDdDIEN.txt     Sample-144-W9eDdDIEN
file_vhTSZfTh.txt      Sample-145-vhTSZfTh
file_b[rj3ft.txt       Sample-146-b[rj3ft
file_]OyWwrVd0RN.txt   Sample-147-]OyWwrVd0RN
(...)
```

From here you can sort the output or whatever else you need

```
$ cat /tmp/list | sed 's/\ \+/ /' | sort  -b -k2.9,2.14n --debug

_________________________________________
file_M7e]VOOHFz.txt Sample-156-M7e]VOOHFz
                           ___
_________________________________________
file_ftb8ifOfYt.txt Sample-157-ftb8ifOfYt
                           ___
_________________________________________
file_tWOa]ZbTA.txt Sample-158-tWOa]ZbTA
                          ___
_______________________________________
file_n4s2Znk.txt Sample-159-n4s2Znk
                        ___
___________________________________
file_mjMox[P.txt Sample-160-mjMox[P
                        ___
___________________________________
file_tQ3.txt Sample-161-tQ3
                    ___
___________________________
file_G6VFcFHYH.txt Sample-162-G6VFcFHYH
                          ___
_______________________________________
file_4mXCFTZaC.txt Sample-163-4mXCFTZaC
                          ___
_______________________________________
```